# Convert a funcition to an anonymous function expression and assign it to a variable

Tags: javascript

Convert the function named `functionDeclaration` to an anonymous function expression and assign it to a variable called `myFunc.`

```
function functionDeclaration() {
  let myFunc = str
   return "Hi there!";
}

console.log(myFunc())
```

I'm new to coding. What am I doing wrong? It's supposed to print 'Hi there!' but keeps giving me a reference error message.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `myFunc` is local to `functionDeclaration`, you can't access it outside of the said function. Also, `str` pops out of nowhere causing an error if you'll ever run this function. I suppose you've missunderstood the task, it asks you to create a variable, which of value is a function.

Answer (score 1):

Your function expression could be like,

```
const func = function functionDeclaration() {
    return "Hi there!";
 }
 
 let myFunc = func()
 console.log(myFunc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `functionDeclaration` is defined like so:

```
function functionDeclaration() {
   return "Hi there!";
}
```

That’s as a function expression:

```js
const myFunc = () => {
   return "Hi there!";
}

console.log(myFunc())
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the purpose of `let myFunc = str`, but give this a try -

```
function functionDeclaration() {
  // let myFunc = str
  return "Hi there!";
}

const myFunc = () => {
  return functionDeclaration.call(this);
}

console.log(myFunc());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer:

```
let myFunc = function() {
    return "Hi there!";
}
```

Please read [Constructor vs. declaration vs. expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#constructor_vs._declaration_vs._expression)

Answer (score 0):

It same as :

```js
const func = function() {
  return `Hi there!`
}
console.log(func())

let myfunc = func
console.log(myfunc())

const func1 = function(name) {
  return `Hi my name is ${name}!`
}
console.log(func1('abc'))

let myfunc1 = func1
console.log(myfunc1('xyz'))

myfunc = func1

console.log(myfunc('123'))
```

Answer (score 0):

function functionDeclaration() {
return "Hi there!"
}

const myFunc = functionDeclaration;
console.log(myFunc())

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).